# Array not filling with records

Tags: php, arrays, variables, select, while-loop

With the first set of code I can print the array, however the second paragraph is meant to store the array into a variable however this is not working any suggestions? the array is empty?

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name FROM adminuser_tbl");
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
    }
  }
```

**Not working below**

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id FROM adminuser_tbl");
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
          $user_list = array();
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
          $user_list[$row->adminuser_id] = $row->admin_name; 
     }
   }
```

If I print the array results from the first paragraph, they all are set to [0]???

```
Array ( [admin_name] => User1 [0] => User1 ) Array ( [admin_name] => User2 [0] => User2 ) Array ( [admin_name] => User3 [0] => User3 ) Array ( [admin_name] => User4 [0] => User4 )
```

Comment: pdo ? fetch mode ? errors ?

Comment: Btw it's `$result = $stmt->execute()` and `$result->fetch()`. Read the documentation of what you use before posting please.

Comment: PDO yes, no errors are thrown up, in the php.

Comment: If I remove the extra () it wont even print the array, I just get a blank page. I get an error then in httpd log, saying it is expecting ( on those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the fetch mode if you want to fetch the rows as object. Default is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which gives you an array with integer and named keys. (See your print_r output)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id FROM adminuser_tbl");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $user_list = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $user_list[$row->adminuser_id] = $row->admin_name;
    }
}
```

Or just use a foreach loop because PDOStatement implements the Traversable interface.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id FROM adminuser_tbl");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $user_list = array();
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $user_list[$row->adminuser_id] = $row->admin_name;
    }
}
```

For the other fetch modes look here: [pdo.constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)